# iOS file renaming thread safety

Tags: ios, multithreading, filesystems

Say I have some data in my iOS app that I want to write to a file.  I use the `writeToFile:atomically:` method on `NSData`, which writes the data to a temp file and then renames the temp file to the location I specified.

Is this operation thread safe?  If I do this writing from a background thread and then happen to ask at a very unfortunate moment from another thread if that file exists (or just grab the contents of that file), is it possible to get an invalid result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition atomically is thread safe, if you grab it before the "Atomic" operation is finished, it will not exist. If you access it after the operation is finished, then it will be ok.

It is similar to the atomic property of properties (that we usually set to nonatomic). It makes sets & gets "atomic", which just means that they happen in "one instant" and there is no in-between state.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the worst that can happen is the file won't be found at the given path. Your app needs to handle this situation correctly.

The Apple documentation for `[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]` has this useful advice (emphasis mine):

> Note: Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of
>   the file system or a particular file on the file system is not
>   recommended. Doing so can cause odd behavior or race conditions. **It's
>   far better to attempt an operation (such as loading a file or creating
>   a directory), check for errors, and handle those errors gracefully
>   than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation
>   will succeed.**